# Generic type for react-query useQuery selector and wrong data type for non-selector hook calls

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

**Code**:

```
export const useAllUsers = <T extends UserResponseDto>(
  select?: (data: UserResponseDto[]) => T
) =>
  useQuery<UserResponseDto[], ErrorResponse, T, string[]>({
    queryKey: [QueryClientKeys.GET_ALL_USERS],
    queryFn: async () => {
      const response = await ApiService.getAllUsers();
      return response.data;
    },
    select: select,
    staleTime: Infinity,
    cacheTime: Infinity,
    retry: false,
  });
```

Is it possible to define the selector for a useQuery hook to return a generic type as above?

With this setup, whenever I use the `useAllUsers` hook **without** passing the `select` function, I get `UserResponseDto` as the `data` type and not `UserResponseDto[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your generic is defined as:

`T extends UserResponseDto`

However, `select` can return anything - it shouldn't be bound to be something that is "assignable to" `UserResponseDto`. But what you'd want to express is that `T` should *default* to `UserResponseDto[]` for cases where you don't provide a `select` function, because `select` is where `useQuery` infers the type of `T` from.

That means you need:

`T = UserResponseDto[]`

instead.

Comment: Thank you! That was it - little troubles with Typescript.

Answer (score 2):

You are telling `useQuery` that the data type returned from it is of type `T extends UserResponseDto`, so in no case could that be `UserResponseDto[]` since `UserResponseDto[]` does not extend `UserResponseDto`.

Do you really mean `<T extends UserResponseDto>`? Because `<T extends UserResponseDto[]>` makes more sense to me and would solve the issue.

If `<T extends UserResponseDto>` is what you want you could do `<T extends unknown = UserResponseDto[]>`, to allow `select` to return any type, but in the same time tell the compiler that if `select` doesn't exist, the data type is `UserResponseDto[]`.